# Preventing Boolean from Junk Value in Object in Rest API Call

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have one Object which has 3 attributes having Integer,String and Boolean Data type in Java,looks like below given REST Body.

```
 {
    "famousForId": 3,
    "name": "Food",
    "activeState": true
 }
```

i've one pojo class which looks like this

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection="famousFor")
public class FamousFor {

//     @Id
     @NotNull
        @PositiveOrZero
     Long famousForId;
     @NotBlank(message = ApplicationUtil.MISSING_FIELD)
     @Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$")
             @Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$",message = "Name Can't Have Special Characters")
     String name;
     @NotNull(message = ApplicationUtil.MISSING_FIELD)
     Boolean activeState;
}
```

and my controller is handling errors properly any junk value for Long and String Value, however if we are passing junk value for Boolean it's without showing any error, it directly throws Http code 400 bad request, i want the proper message for this attribute as well,any help would be highly appreciated.
I'm using Spring boot 2.0.6
My Controller looks something like the below given code block

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/saveFamousForDetails",produces={"application/json"},method=RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity<?> saveEssentialDetails(@ApiParam(value="Body Parameters") @RequestBody @Validated @ModelAttribute("famousFor") FamousFor famousFor, BindingResult bindingResult)throws Exception;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is writing a ExceptionHandler class to your controller using @ControllerAdvice. Override "handleHttpMessageNotReadable" method.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Log4j2
public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException exception,
      HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    // log the error and return whatever you want to
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply,
i have written a custom method something like this

`@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public List<String> handleValidationExceptions(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        return ex.getBindingResult()
                .getAllErrors().stream()
                .map(ObjectError::getDefaultMessage)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }`
annotating  my controller class with @ControllerAdvice

Comment: That'll be called if the data doesn't conform to the validationConstraint you have on the fields of your bean. Your request fails during serialisation of the data, when garbage string is tried to be assigned to boolean. That's when "HttpMessageNotReadableException" is thrown. You'll have to catch that.
Try this in case you don't want to go with above:

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class) 
  public List<String> 
  handleValidationExceptions(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex) 
  { return Arrays.asList(ex.getMessage()); }

Comment: thanks a lot this , gives me a head start to go with the custom Message, however this was good solution.

Comment: And possibly other ways to do similar custom Exception handling: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: @Mavericks Glad it helped. Please consider accepting the answer if it helped. Thanks.